# Versioning system with per file history vs. commit history

Tags: git, version-control, nav, cvs, revision-history

I'm looking for a versioning system, that can show the version history with comments per file.

I've used SVN (not CVS as stated earlier) for a while and have some projects in git.

Both (svn and git) are "commit oriented" (I use this term for lack of a better one): when I look at the repository git shows all the commits, and when I open a commit, I see, which files and changes it contains.

I want it the other way around: I want to see all the files and folders currently in my repository and for each file I see the history of commits it went through.

For each commit I have to enter a summary comment as well as a per file comment describing the file's changes.

The reason I'm looking for this is my NAV (formerly Navision) designer's licence: I am allowed to change objects in my NAV system, but I can't export the sources. Therefore i only have several versions of compiled ".fob" files without any chance to see code changes, so I have to describe the change in a per file comment.

Comment: Last time I checked cvs was just what you wanted, why do you think is it not file-oriented?

Comment: Sorry, my fault: I didn't use CVS but SVN. Just corrected it in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

> I have to describe the change in a per file comment

This goal does not seem like a reason which makes git unsuitable. Basically, you only need to:

- commit each file separately, not all of them at once
- being able to query only commits which change the selected file. Which git is able to do, and is pretty reliable and fast about it, at least if you don't rename the file.

Also, you still can keep together different changes in same commit, if you find them logically coupled, just write there comments about both.

Comment: Usually I don't query files in the repo, but browse (I prefer graphical clients). 
So, what I want is (speaking graphically) klick on a file and see a list of all the commits it took part in, and since most files are binary, I would need a comment for each file commit describing it's changes. 
Still I want to commit several files at once, since they all are part of one major change that needs it's own "master comment"

Comment: @HeinziTuberkel - RClick - find "Log" command (when and if selected SCM-client is shell-extension by implementation)

Answer (score 0):

CVS **is** file-oriented in terms of SCM: for a set of files you can't define single revision and get all files, corresponding to this (revision-slice) state

Use **any** current SCM, but commit single file at a time

Comment: So, isn't that commit oriented then, if I have to create a commit for every single file? Whenever I open my repository I see the list of commits, not the list of files with a history for each file.

Comment: @HeinziTuberkel Yes, you *can* "commit per file". But can also `<SCM-name> log <FILENAME>` and even for combined commits get history of **SINGLE MENTIONED OBJECT**